# How to intercept browser navigation and prompt user in React (including Browser Navigation Away and Tab close)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Here's my scenario:

- I have an editor in a React component that might have unsaved data.
- The only way to know this, for now, is to call a function that returns a boolean.
- So I have to determine if the component has unsaved data when user is trying to  1. navigate away 2. pressed any browser navigation buttons 3. Closed the tab or window.
- I'm using React Router 5

I have tried using Prompt like this:

```
<Prompt
  when={this.getIsEditorDirty()}
  message={location => `Are you sure you want to quit editing ?`}
/>
```

But `when` only takes the value as `state` as expected not through a function. So it doesn't behave correctly.

Since if the editor is dirty or not can be only be known through a function (assuming `getIsEditorDirty()`), I don't seem to find any proper way to intercept any kind of user navigation.

What could be the possible solution or way around here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's still the case in Router 5, but in 4 I do it by returning `true` from function passed as "message" prop if the editor is "clean".

```
    getBlockMessage = () => {
        return this.isChanged() ? LEAVE_MSG : true;
    }

    // ...

    <Prompt message={this.getBlockMessage}/>
```

Comment: Excellent!  Exactly what I was looking for. Who knew `message` could be used like this. Additionally, I've added another answer that will help explain the full implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full implementation of the solution in addition to what @g_ain has posted. This should clarify the solution even further.
This also includes the tricky part where the usage of `when` in `Prompt` is needed to prevent an endless navigation loop. (If you are using a custom Confirmation Modal)

```
//Assuming this is the callback from 
//your custom prompt modal's YES button
onConfirmExitClick() {
  history.push(this.state.nextLocation);
}

shouldShowExitConfirmModal(nextLocation) {
  if (this.getIsEditorDirty()) {
    this.setState({
      nextLocation,
      showExitConfirmModal: true
    });
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

//Inside render()
//Notice the when prop, it doesn't fire when the custom modal is showing
<Prompt
    when={!this.state.showExitConfirmModal}
    message={nextLocation => this.shouldShowExitConfirmModal(nextLocation)}
/>
```